# duplicate data property in object literal is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: android, json, typescript, ionic2

When I run my app in browser (ionic serve -l) everything is alright, even on most android devices there is no problem, but I found some that would not launch app and die on error above device. I have problem with runs on android 5.0.2. I even tried to turn off strict mode in tsconfig.json, but no success. Did someone experience similar problem or is there any way how to find out where exactly the problem is?

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "diagnostics": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": true,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "es2015"
        ],
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
      }    

}
```

Comment: This is not a valid json structure

Comment: that is true, just forgot add that "{" in this post

Answer (score 0):

You have all these options to configure strict Type-Checking:

```
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */        
    "strict": true,                        /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
```

Note that "strict" configuration was added in TypeScript 2.3

Comment: Tried all these, but no success, looks like strict mode is still on.

Comment: do you have "use strict" in your TS or JS files ?

Comment: 'use strict' is in JS files